# Eclipse IDE makes nearly all Java projects invalid

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, compilation

So, I was programming some plugins for my MC server using Spigot API. {...}   It all worked perfectly fine yesterday before I went to sleep. I compiled the plugins, put them on my server & they worked. So my code was good. Today, I just wake up & Eclipse shows me that there's an error in every Java project. I open up the project and the code (obviously) remains the same as before, with no errors. The project properties are set to JRE1.8 & compliance version 1.8 which all worked perfectly fine before. I could ignore it but it stops Eclipse from actually compiling what I wrote - instead it compiles the version that worked last for some reason. Last time I had this error, I took the code, created an identical Java Project & just pasted the code in there. It worked. I don't wanna do that for all of my Java Projects though, any way to fix it - or does perhaps, someone know why that error happens?

TLDR; Eclipse Java Projects can't be compiled to what I just wrote cause project shows error - but there's no error in my code

[image]

Comment: can you just rebuild and run? maybe also try to restart eclipse

Comment: yes, somewhere there is an error, being it in code or in config. But you show way to little details/context for us to even guess

Comment: Rebuilding doesn't work & restarting doesn't change anything as well.

Comment: @Stultuske okay, but why does the code work then? And why does it have no errors if I copy & paste exactly the same code in a new Java Project with literally the same files?

Comment: It can't be compiled, yet it has no errors? not being able to compile is what I would consider an error.

Comment: It can be compiled, but it compiles it to the last version which apparently had no errors (yesterday evening).. Which is exactly the same as now.

Comment: I added an image, not that it helps much since I can't show all lines. But as you can see, nothing in the code is marked red. The opened project with Main.java is EdgeCutter btw

Comment: What I forgot: You can see errors at the scrollbar on the right in the currently opened java file.. There are none shown as well. Like I said, It's still the same code as yesterday which works perfectly fine. Just if I were to add something to the code now it wouldn't do it.

Comment: What about the view "Problems" that usually goes at the bottom of the screen? We can see some marked projects but you have not posted the information that Eclipse is providing you about the error.

Comment: The tricky part with these kind of occurrences is that you can't point the finger at Eclipse; usually it is a specific plugin/extension that hurts and those things are versioned and updated separately from the IDE itself. You can't just ask "how do I fix this Eclipse problem", there are any number of potential sources for it to happen. This can happen in any IDE really. You might say "I didn't install any plugins" - yes you did. They even come with the base installations.

Comment: @RubioRic cause it wasn't providing any.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed it. The way I didn't want to fix it. I created a new Java Project & basically copy / pasted everything exactly identical in there. It worked but I hate doing that.

Comment: Show the `.classpath` files of the old and of the new project (I guess you've been referring to a JRE that no longer exists, which is something you shouldn't do; for this case there are smarter solutions than what you are doing).

Comment: They were all referring to the right JRE that my new project is referring to as well.

Comment: You have to refer to an execution environment, not to a specific JRE. There is a good chance that you will face the same issue again. Work smart not hard to not hate yourself.